# C++ Minmax Failing

Tags: c++, minimax, minmax

I've been working on this for such a long time that it isn't funny anymore. I'm trying to implement Minmax on Tic Tac Toe and while I have gotten several versions of AI that make reasonable initial moves, I can never make one that never loses.

One of the issues which I cannot sort out is the heuristic value. It is currently returning as -10 on the first Minmax call, whereas it should be returning 0 (It should be able to draw no matter what happens).

Another issue is that it runs through 400,000 iterations, whereas 322,000 is the max and given early win situations, should even stop around 250,000.

Any help would be infinitely appreciated.

```
int MiniMax(TGameBoard _GameBoard)
{
    //Always goes for max of course, just expanded in case you wanted two AIs

    int iBestMove;      
    int iHeuristicReturned = 0;

    if (_GameBoard.ePlayer == COMPUTER)
    {
        iHeuristicReturned = MaxMove(_GameBoard, iBestMove);
    }
    else
    {
        iHeuristicReturned = MinMove(_GameBoard, iBestMove);
    }
    //cout<<"\nHeuristic is "<<iHeuristicReturned<<endl;

    g_iHeuristic = iHeuristicReturned;
    return iBestMove;
}

int MaxMove(TGameBoard _GameBoard, int& _iMove)
{
    //Logic
    //If its an end node, calculate the score
    //Otherwise, do minmax until the end node, and pass back the value
    //If returned value is greater than v, then pass the move back upwards
    ++g_iIterations;
    if(_GameBoard.CheckWinner(_GameBoard) || _GameBoard.IsFull())
    {
        int x;
        x = EvaluateStaticPosition(_GameBoard, MAX);
        return EvaluateStaticPosition(_GameBoard, MAX);
    }
    vector<int> moveList;
    GenerateMoveList(_GameBoard, moveList);
    int iNumMoves = moveList.size();
    int v = -10000;

    for(int i = 0; i < iNumMoves; ++i)
    {
        int iMove = moveList[i];

        _GameBoard.Set(iMove, CROSS);
        int opponentsBestMove;
        ++g_iDepth;
        int curRating = MinMove(_GameBoard, opponentsBestMove);
        --g_iDepth;
        if (curRating > v)
        {
            v = curRating;
            _iMove = iMove;
        }
        RetractMove(&_GameBoard, iMove);
    }
    return v;
}

int MinMove(TGameBoard _GameBoard, int& _iMove)
{
    ++g_iIterations;
    if (g_iIterations > 320000)
    {
        int x = 0;
    }

    if(_GameBoard.CheckWinner(_GameBoard) || _GameBoard.IsFull())
    {
        return EvaluateStaticPosition(_GameBoard, MIN);
    }

    vector<int> moveList;
    GenerateMoveList(_GameBoard, moveList);
    int iNumMoves = moveList.size();
    int v = 10000;

    for(int i = 0; i < iNumMoves; ++i)
    {
        int iMove = moveList[i];
        _GameBoard.Set(iMove, NAUGHT);
        int opponentsBestMove;
        ++g_iDepth;
        int curRating = MaxMove(_GameBoard, opponentsBestMove);
        --g_iDepth;
        if (curRating < v)
        {
            v = curRating;
            _iMove = iMove;
        }
        RetractMove(&_GameBoard, iMove);
    }
    return v;
}

int EvaluateStaticPosition(TGameBoard _GameBoard, EGoal _eGoal)
{
    if(_GameBoard.CheckWinner(_GameBoard, COMPUTER))
    {
        return 10;
    } 
    if(_GameBoard.CheckWinner(_GameBoard, PLAYER))
    {
        return -10;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

The other related functions can be checked here, but I'm pretty sure they're okay.
http://pastebin.com/eyaNfBsq

Yes I'm aware there's a few unnecessary parameters - After failing my own version I tried follow a tutorial off the internet. Unfortunately they're giving the same results.

I've been on this for 12 hours and it seems such a simple task, can't find out what's wrong

Comment: About the numbers of iterations, your count is incorrect, you count the number of symbol "played". Suppose you have 2 empty cells, expected result of iteration is 2, but you will have 4. In my version I got 265140 iterations and 9! = 362880.

Comment: MaxMove and MinMove may be factorized by giving player and computing score according to player (min(a,b,c, ...) == max(-a,-b,-c,-...)).

Comment: Thanks Jarod
In my original version I had this as a single recursive function however I split it up so that I could follow it easier. When I get it working, I'll chuck it all back into my original version.

I didn't quite follow why I'm getting double iterations though. Can you explain more?

Comment: I suggest you to debug, first with trivial cases (not a empty board) to see where the problem is. You may also use its "better" game and redo the play until it is wrong.

Comment: Explanation of double iteration: with 2 empty cells a,b: you call maxMove (+1), play aX -> Minmove (+1) play bO -> MaxMove (+1) board full -> backtrack... play bX -> MinMove (+1) play aO -> MaxMove(+1): board full -> End : total 5 iterations where as there is only 2 choices (play a or b, other player is forced), or else you count 4 possibilities (aX, aXbO, bX, bXaO) but in that case the max number of possibilities is more than 9! it should be 9! + 9!/2 + 9!/3! + ... + 9!/8!

Comment: the board is 3x3 each cell has 3 possible states, then the total number of possible games is 3^9 wich is only 19683 possible grid configurations. however real configurations are much lesser because many configurations are not possible (for example all 9 cells filled with "o" or "x" etc). Ho the heck did you found (9!) O_O ??

Comment: @DarioOO: explanation of 9!: player1 has the choice between 9 cells, then player2 has the choice between 8 cells, players1 between 7 cells, and so on. For a total of `9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1` so 9! games (with some games which result in same board, and with some games which finished before the board is full).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may help you:

(Bonus: alphabeta with less than 8000 boards examined.)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

enum class Square
{
    Empty,
    O,
    X
};

Square other(Square c) {
    switch (c) {
        case Square::O: return Square::X;
        case Square::X: return Square::O;
        default: assert(0); return Square::Empty;
    };
}

template <typename STREAM>
STREAM& operator << (STREAM& stream, Square c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case Square::Empty: stream << "."; break;
        case Square::X: stream << "X"; break;
        case Square::O: stream << "O"; break;
    }
    return stream;
}

class Board
{
public:
    Board() : board({{Square::Empty, Square::Empty, Square::Empty,
                    Square::Empty, Square::Empty, Square::Empty,
                    Square::Empty, Square::Empty, Square::Empty}})
    {}

    void display() const {
        for (int y = 0; y != 3; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x) {
                std::cout << board[3 * y + x] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void play(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Square c)
    {
        assert(x < 3);
        assert(y < 3);

        board[3 * y + x] = c;
    }
    void play(unsigned int offset, Square c)
    {
        assert(offset < 9);

        board[offset] = c;
    }

    bool isFull() const {
        return std::find(board.cbegin(), board.cend(), Square::Empty) == board.cend();
    }

    int computeScore(Square c) const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (board[3 * i] != Square::Empty && board[3 * i] == board[3 * i + 1] && board[3 * i] == board[3 * i + 2]) {
                return board[3 * i] == c ? 1 : -1;
            }
            if (board[i] != Square::Empty && board[i] == board[i + 3] && board[i] == board[i + 6]) {
                return board[i] == c ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
        if (board[4] == Square::Empty) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ((board[4] == board[0] && board[4] == board[8])
            || (board[4] == board[2] && board[4] == board[6])) {
            return board[4] == c ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int minmax(Square c, unsigned int* counter, unsigned int* pos = NULL)
    {
        const int currentScore = computeScore(c);
        if (currentScore != 0 || isFull()) {
            if (counter) {++*counter; }
            return currentScore;
        }
        int bestScore = -10;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
            if (board[i] != Square::Empty) { continue; }

            play(i, c);
            int score = -minmax(other(c), counter);
            if (bestScore < score) {
                bestScore = score;
                if (pos) { *pos = i; }
            }
            play(i, Square::Empty);
        }
        return bestScore;
    }

    int alphabeta(Square c, int alpha, int beta, unsigned int* counter, unsigned int* pos = NULL)
    {
        const int currentScore = computeScore(c);
        if (currentScore != 0 || isFull()) {
            if (counter) {++*counter; }
            return currentScore;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
            if (board[i] != Square::Empty) { continue; }

            play(i, c);
            int score = -alphabeta(other(c), -beta, -alpha, counter);
            if (beta <= score) {
                if (pos) { *pos = i; }
                play(i, Square::Empty);
                return score;
            }
            if (alpha < score) {
                alpha = score;
                if (pos) { *pos = i; }
            }
            play(i, Square::Empty);
        }
        return alpha;
    }

private:
    std::array<Square, 9> board;
};

int main()
{
    Board b;
    Square c = Square::X;

    while (b.computeScore(Square::X) == 0 && b.isFull() == false) {
        std::cout << c << " to play" << std::endl;
        b.display();
        unsigned int counter = 0;
        unsigned int pos;
        const int s = b.minmax(c, &counter, &pos);
        //const int s = b.alphabeta(c, -10, 10, &counter, &pos);
        b.play(pos, c);
        std::cout << "score for "<< c <<" = " << s << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#final boards examined = " << counter << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
        c = other(c);
    }
    std::cout << "Final score for X = " << b.computeScore(Square::X) << std::endl;
    b.display();

    return 0;
}
```

The count of "iterations" is the number of final board examined.